# Can I create a new Google Apps user with the same email address as an existing alias?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I’ve got an Google Apps for Business account, in which I have a main email address that I use for everything related to my company—`studio@...`

I created an alias of this called `careers@...` which I used for job applicants to send in their CVs. I then setup a rule to move all of the `careers` emails to a folder called careers to keep my main inbox clean.

Now this careers folder is taking up almost all of the space in my mail account and I want to move it to its own account rather than just an alias.

But when I try to create the account, also called `careers@...` it says this account already exists (I believe it's getting confused by the alias).

Is there a way round this?

Comment: But when you create an "account", doesn't it create an email address for that account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Even though `careers@` is an alias, G Suite sees it as an existing address. Incoming emails would not know which is the correct `careers@`. If you were to create a group with the name `careers@` you would get the same error.

You need to delete the alias and then create `careers@`'s own account.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071113?hl=en